# finding schemaLocation in c# XmlSchema

Tags: c#, xsd

i have the following schema loaded into an xmlSchema :

```
...
<xs:import schemaLocation="\_1.xsd" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
...
```

i want to retrive the string "_1.xsd"

how do i reach the schemaLocation value from XmlSchema API ?
will schemaSet work better ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i finally used this :

```
schema.Includes[0] as XmlSchemaImport;
var wsdlId = schemaImport.SchemaLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

This should work, might throw some errors, as I didnt compile it in an IDE as im not on a Dev machine atm.

```
string xsd = "example.xsd";

FileStream fs;
XmlSchema schema;

fs = new FileStream(xsd, FileMode.Open);
schema = XmlSchema.Read(fs, new ValidationEventHandler(ShowCompileError));

foreach (XmlSchemaObject externalSchema in schema.Includes)
{
    string schemaLoc = (XmlSchemaExternal)externalSchema.SchemaLocation.ToString();
}
```